# Top, center align 3 divs on my master page

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm simply trying to make 3 divs sit on top without too much space being wasted.
One div is simply a logo image, another a search box, and finally the last at the right div is simply a login / logout control.

My css is very poor, and I've tried floating the first div left and the right most div right and keeping the search bar in the middle but it doesn't look right.  Here is my html:

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="maia-header-logo" class="float-left;">
        </div>
        <div id="searchbox">
                <input runat="server" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here..." />
                <input runat="server" id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <p>
                                Hello, <a id="hlManageAccount" runat="server" class="username" href="#" title="Manage your account">
                                    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" CssClass="username" /></a> | <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                            </p>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </section>
         </div>
    </div>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your CSS please?

Comment: I don't have really any except the design of the search box.  I tried to make the `main` div 100% and each other div 33% but that didn't work.  Do I need to inline the divs?

Comment: Then how did you manage to produce your screenshot? ;)

Comment: @gvee just by running the html...

Comment: Post the rendered HTML (not the ASP) and your CSS.

Comment: no css....bt you have image....have you copied the searchbox code from somewhere!!!????

Comment: The image css is `#maia-header-logo {
 background: url("../images/RIMS64.png") no-repeat left bottom;min-height: 64px;
}`

Comment: The search from here:  http://www.awcore.com/url/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5yZWQtdGVhbS1kZXNpZ24uY29tL2hvdy10by1jcmVhdGUtYS1jb29sLWFuZC11c2FibGUtY3NzMy1zZWFyY2gtYm94

Comment: add `float:left` to css in all three classes...this should do!

Answer (score 0):

If you define your widths, they should all sit at the top.

Otherwise you can create a fixed width container, set it as `position: relative;` then position your top bar with relative positioning,

```
#header-container {
    position:relative;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto; }
#maia-header-logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; }
#searchbox { 
    width: 500px; /* exact width of element */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 250px; /* (containerWidth - elementWidth) / 2 */ }
#login {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
    left: 750px; }
```

Since I don't have the exact measurements for your site, I can't do the math for you, but the equation is simple enough.